# How to extract value from a url

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a few requests coming in which follow the pattern below

> contacts/id/
>
> contacts/x/id/name
>
> contacts/x/y/id/address
>
> contacts/z/address/

I want to extract the value which follows right after 'contacts'

In above cases,

```
1. id  
2. x 
3. x 
4. z
```

Here is my regex

```
(?<=contacts)\/[^\/]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/ePmv5Y/1

But it is matching along with the trailing '/' for eg. /id, /x etc

How do I optimize to get rid of this trailing slash?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match()` here:

```js
var urls = ["contacts/id/", "contacts/x/id/name", "contacts/x/y/id/address", "contacts/z/address/"];
for (var i=0; i < urls.length; ++i) {
    var output = urls[i].match(/\bcontacts\/(.*?)\//)[1];
    console.log(urls[i] + " => " + output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a few requests coming in

If you mean http requests, then this is likely the [pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) of the requested URL, and they'll start with a `/`. (This is the value of [`req.url`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#messageurl) in a Node.js server.)

To match on a URL pathname, you can use this expression: `^\/contacts\/([^/?]+)`. Here's a link to another regular expression builder that demonstrates it and includes an explanation for every character: https://regexr.com/6tugf

The `[^/?]` is a *negated set* that matches any token which is not a `/` or a `?` and the `+` means that it matches 1 or more of those tokens. It's important to include the `?` because otherwise it could match into the query string portion of the URL — for example, in this URL:

```
https://domain.tld/contacts/x/id/name?filter=recent # URL
                  /contacts/x/id/name?filter=recent # req.url in Node.js
                  /contacts/x/id/name               # pathname
                                     ?filter=recent # query string
```

And here's a runnable code snippet demonstrating the same expression, using [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
const contactIdRegexp = /^\/contacts\/([^/?]+)/;

const inputs = [
  '/contacts/id/', // id
  '/contacts/x/id/name', // x
  '/contacts/x/y/id/address', // x
  '/contacts/z/address/', // z
  '/contacts/x/id/name?filter=recent', // x
];

for (const str of inputs) {
  const id = str.match(contactIdRegexp)?.[1];
  console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: thank you, this solution worked for my requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `/` inside the lookbehind:

```
(?<=contacts\/)[^\/]+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JWWnxu/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you like to continue without regex, You can try below.

```
//get the URL object.
const url = new URL(`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}${req.originalUrl}`);

//extract the pathname and split using "/"
const pathName= url.pathname.split("/");

//get the required value using array index.
const val = pathName[2];
```

Comment: Thank you @Bishan, this is a good solution but at the moment my requirement is to use Regex.